# How to add results in a for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, probability

I created a program that can calculate the probability:

```
() = ((!)/(x!)((N-x)!))*(^x)*(1-p)^(−)
```

The program was working perfectly fine when you entered the value of `N`, `x` and `p`.

However, I also need to compute the sum of the probabilities within a given range of x. So I added the low end of x and the high end of x in the program. I am now having trouble with the equation because I am not able to find the sum of the probabilities. I am trying to make a for loop but I keep on getting the following message: "Code will never be executed".

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


double factorial (double N, double x, double p);
double tgamma (double N, double x, double p);

int main ()
{
    double N;
    double xlow;
    double xhigh;
    double p;
    double Probability;
    double result;

    {
        cout << "Input N value" << endl;
        cin >> N;
        {
            cout << "Input low end of x Value" << endl;
            cin >> xlow;
            while(xlow<0 || xlow>N){
                cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
                cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
                cin >> xlow;
            }
            {
                cout << "Input high endx Value" << endl;
                cin >> xhigh;
                while(xhigh<0 || xhigh>N){
                    cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
                    cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
                    cin >> xhigh;
                }
            }
            cout << "Input p value" << endl;
            cin >> p;
            while(p<0 || p>1){
                cout << "p value is NOT a real number between 0 and 1." << endl;
                cout << "Input p value" << endl;
                cin >> p;
            }
            double Probability;
            Probability=result;
        }
        return 0;

    }

    double factorial (double N, double xlow, double xhigh, double p, double       Probability);

    for (xlow=0; xlow <= xhigh; ++xlow){

        result =((tgamma((N+1)))/((tgamma(xlow+1)) * ((tgamma(((N-xlow+1))))))) * (pow(p,xlow)) * (pow((1-p),(N-xlow)));
        Probability += result;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Here is my updated code based on your recommendations!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


double factorial (double N, double x, double p);
double tgamma (double N, double x, double p);

int main ()
{
double N;
double xlow;
double xhigh;
double p;
double Probability;
double result;

{
cout << "Input N value" << endl;
cin >> N;

cout << "Input low end of x Value" << endl;
cin >> xlow;
while(xlow<0 || xlow>N){
    cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
    cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
    cin >> xlow;
}

cout << "Input high endx Value" << endl;
cin >> xhigh;
while(xhigh<0 || xhigh>N){
        cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
        cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
        cin >> xhigh;
}

cout << "Input p value" << endl;
cin >> p;
while(p<0 || p>1){
    cout << "p value is NOT a real number between 0 and 1." << endl;
    cout << "Input p value" << endl;
    cin >> p;
}
    double Probability;
    Probability=result;
}




double factorial (double N, double xlow, double xhigh, double p);

for (xlow=0; xlow <= xhigh; ++xlow){

result =((tgamma((N+1)))/((tgamma(xlow+1)) * ((tgamma(((N-xlow+1))))))) * (pow(p,xlow)) * (pow((1-p),(N-xlow)));
Probability += result;
}

}
```

Comment: you have a semicolon after your factorial function declaration...?

Comment: When I don't put the semicolon, the program tells me to put one.

Comment: You apparently have mismatched braces.

Comment: What do you mean by mismatched braces exactly?

Comment: your braces makes me want to cry

Comment: and why you declared `Probability` twice ?

Comment: I double checked the braces and their is the same amount of braces opening than closing.

Comment: I will take off the second Probability declaration, thank you!

Comment: This code has many unneeded braces and parentheses `{}` and `()`. Try removing those you don't need, and it will be much easier to understand.

Comment: Understood, I will do that!

Comment: What is that `factorial` declaration supposed to do?

Comment: To be honest I forgot why it is there. I am taking it off.

Comment: @anatolyg where did you edit the code?

Comment: @Jaaadeee I used MS Visual Studio to fix indentation (press Alt+F8). You can do it in most IDEs (e.g. M-x `indent-region` in Emacs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
    return 0;
```

will prevent the rest of your `main` function from running. Delete it.

Comment: Does my for loop make sense given the fact that I am trying to do the sum of probabilities? @TheDark
For example: P(0<=x<=3) = P(x=0)+P(x=1)+P(x=2)+P(x=3).

Comment: It seems this answer fixed the original problem. @Jaaadeee if this is the case, you should accept this answer (using the check-mark near it) to indicate that it helped, and your question is answered.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that!

Comment: @Jaaadeee Yes, it makes sense to add up the probabilities like that, provided that the individual probabilities for all values of x sum up to 1. Note: I didn't look at your equation to determine if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes. Using the "while" condition made this code work properly. The following code calculates the sum of probabilities:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


double factorial (double N, double x, double p);
double tgamma (double N, double x, double p);

int main ()
{
double N;
double xlow;
double xhigh;
double p;
double Probability;
double result;


cout << "Input N value" << endl;
cin >> N;

cout << "Input low end of x Value" << endl;
cin >> xlow;
while(xlow<0 || xlow>N){
    cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
    cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
    cin >> xlow;
}

cout << "Input high endx Value" << endl;
cin >> xhigh;
while(xhigh<0 || xhigh>N){
        cout << "x value is NOT between 0 and N." << endl;
        cout << "Input x Value" << endl;
        cin >> xhigh;
}

cout << "Input p value" << endl;
cin >> p;
while(p<0 || p>1){
    cout << "p value is NOT a real number between 0 and 1." << endl;
    cout << "Input p value" << endl;
    cin >> p;
}


while (xlow <= xhigh){

result =((tgamma((N+1)))/((tgamma(xlow+1)) * ((tgamma(((N-xlow+1))))))) * (pow(p,xlow)) * (pow((1-p),(N-xlow)));
    Probability += result;
    ++xlow;
}
cout << "Sum of Probabilities is: " << Probability << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `((tgamma((N+1)))/((tgamma(xlow+1)) * ((tgamma(((N-xlow+1))))))) * (pow(p,xlow)) * (pow((1-p),(N-xlow)))` could be better written as `tgamma(N+1)/(tgamma(xlow+1) * tgamma(N-xlow+1)) * pow(p,xlow) * pow(1-p,N-xlow)` ((I am writing this because it was fun removing these ((unneeded)) (parentheses)))